# How to install and use gerrit with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, githooks, gerrit

I want know how to install and use **gerrit** in **eclipse**.
I does not found any easy and helpful documentation for the same.

I already have Git plugin installed in eclipse and I am using it, now I want to know about the **gerrit**.

I went through this link [Enabling_Gerrit_for_your_Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Gerrit#Enabling_Gerrit_for_your_Eclipse.org_Project) but they are asking me to give infromation about project and the repository URL..Can it will be possible without these information??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Link that you mentioned talks about how to enable Gerrit only for Eclipse.org developers, not for general public like you.

You can install [Gerrit Mylyn plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/reviews/gerrit/), however it is still beta quality and lacks serious documentation.

In real life, I prefer to use [`repo`](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html) and `repo upload` to submit code reviews, and track them via standard Gerrit web interface.

While `repo` was designed by Android project, it is very generic tool and can be used for any other project (but only on Mac or Linux, not Windows, unfortunately). `repo` has excellent integration with Gerrit to submit your code.